# vb.net Printing time and datetime

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, printing

I have data to print which is from the table in database and it works but I have a column `Date` with datatype `datetime` and a column `Time` with datatype `datetime`.

- Date column: 9/9/2013 12:00:00 AM
- Time column: 4/13/2013 10:00:00 AM

in printing data it should be like this

- Date column: 9/9/2013
- Time column:10:00:00 AM

Can anyone help me in this kind of problem

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need two columns? One column is sufficient to keep date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vb.net you can use `DateTime` datatype to retrieve data:

```
Dim myDate as DateTime = ...
```

Then you can get the formatted string of data value

```
texBox.Text = myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

And for time use `"HH:mm:ss"` or `"T"`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx